# Install Sample Data on Enterprise 1.14

Tags: sample-data, enterprise-1.14

I am attempting to install the sample data for 1.9 on Magento EE 1.14. I did this when 1.14 came out and I eventually got it to work, but now I can't remember what I did.

After starting the install I come up with this error

```
app/code/core/Enterprise/WebsiteRestriction/data/enterprise_websiterestriction_setup/data-install-1.11.0.0.php" - A page URL key for specified store already exists.
```

So I then dropped my database and imported an already running version of 1.9 sample data and attempted to upgrade it with magerun

```
$ magerun sys:setup:run
Error in file: "app/code/core/Enterprise/WebsiteRestriction/data/enterprise_websiterestriction_setup/data-install-1.11.0.0.php" - A page URL key for specified store already exists.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get past this I simple commented out the update to the cms on this

```
app/code/core/Enterprise/WebsiteRestriction/data/enterprise_websiterestriction_setup/data-install-1.11.0.0.php
```

Not sure if it matters since this is all just sample data